# Config file in multi project solution

Tags: c#, .net, configuration-files

I have a Solution where one project is the Data layer and the other project is the web front-end, which has the DL project as a reference. DL project have its own app.config file which stores connection strings used by Linq-to -Sql (.dbml) file. The web front end also has a web.Config file where it has its own settings.

How Do 
I need to make the DL project to use the connection string from Web.config file of Web front end and not from the app.config file?

Basically, if I refer the Data Layer in any WebApp, it would pick the values from web.config and not from the app.config file in the DL project

Comment: I would go for a solution not using .config files. But that is just me.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the relevant configuration from the DL .config file into the web.config file. It should work that way.